# Creating a view with multiple COUNT rows

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm attempting to create a view from a table, the view should consist of several counts from the table.

The Table consists of two columns, column 1 is OrderNr and Column 2 is KladNr. The view should count how many of a specific KladNr there is, for example there is 4x of 1.

```
CREATE VIEW MostPop AS
SELECT KladNr, COUNT(KladNr) FROM OrderContent WHERE KladNr = 1;
```

So this would give me a view with two columns, KladNr and 'COUNT(KladNr)', the first row is 1 (For KladNr 1) and 4 (the number of rows with KladNr = 1).

The issue is I'd like to repeat this COUNT for 2-5 as well, aka KladNr 2-5. So I'd want to create a view which consists of how many rows of each specific KladNr.

Comment: Please add some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: `COUNT(x)` counts how many rows have `x IS NOT NULL`.  `COUNT(DISTINCT x)` counts the number if different values of `x` exist.  `COUNT(*)` is usually the "right" thing to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT KladNr, COUNT(*)
FROM OrderContent 
GROUP BY KladNr;
```

If you want separate columns, use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(kladnr = 1) as kladnr_1,
       sum(kladnr = 2) as kladnr_2,
       sum(kladnr = 3) as kladnr_3,
       sum(kladnr = 4) as kladnr_4,
       sum(kladnr = 5) as kladnr_5
from OrderContent;
```

Comment: You're a legit wizard, with my extremely poor explanation you just literally solved it. Thanks alot!

Comment: Is there anyway to order the view (descending) in relation to the Count Column?
EDIT; Solved with ORDER BY COUNT(*)

Comment: @LinusLiljequist . . . You can include the `order by` in the view.  I even think MariaDB might recognize the `ORDER BY` even though the standard and other databases would either not allow it or ignore it.